# Necesito que obligue a cambiar mi TextView

Tags: java, android

Tengo un `TextView` que relleno con `DatePickerDialog`y `TimePickerDialog` , también tengo que por defecto se añada automáticamente la *fecha* y *hora* del día en el que estamos, pues aquí está mi problema. Tengo puesto que necesite rellenar el `TextView` para poder avanzar, si lo dejas en blanco te sale un mensaje pidiendo que rellenes el `TextView` pero como he dicho arriba, por defecto te añade la *hora* y *fecha* por lo tanto nunca está vacío.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que reconozca como vacío mi `TextView` cuando por defecto se añada la *hora* y *fecha*

O planteándolo de otra forma, que no reconozca que esta relleno con el texto automático

Aquí mi código: (La clase no está completa, solamente lo que opino que se necesita para intentar solucionar mi problema)

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            editTextFecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);

            Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            mostrarFecha();

            selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    dia = dayOfMonth;
                    mes = month;
                    ano = year;
                    mostrarFecha();
                    mostrarHora();
                }
            };

        }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
                case 0:
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, selectorFecha, ano, mes, dia);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
            showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
        }


        public void mostrarFecha() {
            editTextFecha.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano + " " + hora + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos));

        }

        private void mostrarHora() {
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            hora = hourOfDay;
                            minutos = minute;
                            mostrarFecha();
                        }
                    }, hora, minutos, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }

        // aqui compruebo que los campos estén rellenos, en este caso `Fecha` es lo que estamos mirando

                btnguardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (verificarCampoNombre() && verificarCampoFecha()
                        && verificarCampoZodiaco()) {
                    if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                        editarPersona();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            abc_id = (int)insertarNuevoPersona();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    finish();
                } else {
                    if (editTextNombre.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto(getResources().getString(R.string.intro_nombre));
                    }
                    if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto(getResources().getString(R.string.intro_fecha));
                    }
                    if (editTextZodiaco.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto(getResources().getString(R.string.intro_zodiaco));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

 private boolean verificarCampoFecha() {
        if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

        }
    }
```

¿Es posible? O tengo que quitar que se añada automáticamente la *fecha* y *hora*

Comment: En mi opinión tu problema, más que de código, es de concepción de tu aplicación. Si quieres hacer algo contradictorio: "hacer que algo que tiene datos sea reconocido como algo que no lo tiene" significa que hay un error en la forma en que estás concibiendo tu programa. Eso no significa que no se pueda hacer lo que planteas en la pregunta, pero si resuelves la contradicción que te refiero analizando de nuevo la forma en que la app debe funcionar, te ahorrarás muchos dolores de cabeza ahora y para el futuro.

Comment: Solamente quiero que reconozca que no tiene datos cuando se escribe automáticamente por primera vez la fecha y hora, planteándolo de otra forma que no reconozca que esta relleno con el texto automático @A.Cedano

Comment: Eso puedes hacerlo por ejemplo a través de un campo de tu clase de tipo booleano (true/false), supongamos que lo llamas bolFecha . Le puedes asignar un valor false por defecto y true solamente cuando es llamado el método que escribe la fecha de forma automática. Luego evalúas bolFecha: si es true significa que la fecha se llenó de forma automática, si es false significa que, o no hay fecha rellenada o se rellenó por otra vía. Creo que también se puede hacer con operaciones de tipo "binding", determinando si una determinada variable ha cambiado de valor o no.

Comment: Finalmente seguí tu consejo y decidí ir por otro lado, ya que me estaba liando mucho, tenía el código muy liado y todo me era más difícil, por favor, añade una respuesta con este comentario y te lo marco como útil, ya que me has ayudado bastante! Estoy empezando y opiniones de gente que sabe me vienen muy bien, gracias ! @A.Cedano

Comment: Por favor @A.Cedano crea una respuesta con tu primer comentario para marcarlo como solución ya que es el que me ha solucionado mi problema. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de haber visto varios detalles de tu código he llegado a la conclusión de que tu problema, más que de código, es de concepción de tu aplicación.

Si quieres hacer algo contradictorio: "hacer que algo que tiene datos sea reconocido como algo que no lo tiene" significa que hay un error en la forma en que estás concibiendo tu programa.

Eso no significa que no se pueda hacer lo que planteas en la pregunta, pero si resuelves la contradicción que te refiero analizando de nuevo la forma en que la app debe funcionar, te ahorrarás muchos dolores de cabeza ahora y para el futuro.

Muchas veces, es cierto, tenemos errores que podríamos llamar "físicos", como un `Null Pointer Exception`u otros, pero en muchos casos dichos errores se producen porque la lógica que estamos siguiendo para nuestro programa es algo tortuosa.

A veces hay soluciones muy fáciles para cosas que parecen complicadas, y cuando nuestro código parece que se complica demasiado, conviene dar marcha atrás porque casi seguro que en alguna parte hay un **error lógico**, un **error de diseño** u otro que hace difícil soluciones que, corregido ese error, son muy simples de implementar.

Comment: Gracias a tu explicación conseguí mirar el problema desde otro lado y solucionarlo, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Lo que a mi se me ocurre es que uses la propiedad hint(que es un texto digamos de fondo, el que se ocupa regularmente en los formularios pero en realidad no se almacena en su propiedad .text del en este caso textview, entonces podrías llenar ese hint con la fecha automática y aunque de primer momento se mostrará en el textview no lo almacenará como texto, en valor text, seguirá teniendo valor "" , o el que tu le quieras poner como valor al iniciar tu programa

```
private TextView text2hint;




     text2hint=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProbarhint);
     text2hint.setText("");

     text2hint.setHint("FECHA");
```

O para tu método algo así

```
 public void mostrarFecha() {
            editTextFecha.setHint(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano + " " + hora + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos));

        }
```

Comment: Lo pensé, pero entonces cuando selecciono una fecha y hora en mi `TimePickerDialog` y `DatePickerDialog` también lo envía como *Hint* y me dice que está vacío @EmmO